# How to overlap point on grouped boxplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created the following grouped ggplot boxplot that lists 6 variables along the X axis, a numerical variable along the y axis, and two groups within each x variable. I want to overlay a point from a different data set (i.e. cannot use stat_summary) onto each of the bars but I can't seem to figure out how to do this. I have tried to add the points manually one by one but it doesn't seem to register that there are two barplots within each x variable.

```
gg_trial <- ggplot(longer_, aes(x = g_whoregion, y = value, color = name)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(x = "AFR", y = 27043, col = name), col = "red")
```

This is what I got when I tried to add one point manually

[image: This is what I got when I tried to add one point manually]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: you need to add a position argument to the geom_point. something like geom_point(..., position = "dodge")

Comment: what happens when you add an empty (no argument) `geom_point()`?

Comment: @Dylan_Gomes I get points added in between the two bars and at the key points (median, range)

Comment: Try to [add your data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rn6BgT15yIs), or a sample of it, so we can help you better.